# How to dynamically generate a button with a Command parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

In c#, how can you dynamically generate a button and assign it a Command parameter?

Right now I have

```
newButton.Text = "Answer Question";
newButton.CommandArgument = q.GetHashCode().ToString();
newButton.Command += answer;
```

To generate the button. The answer function looks at bit like

```
protected void answer(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string question = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    //do stuff
}
```

But the button does nothing when pressed. What kind of commands are necessary to make something like this work?

Comment: generating controls dynamically is a bad idea for webforms. the controls are always destroyed on postback and have to be recreated each time. the reason your answer function is not being called is that, when you clicked the button postback happened and the button itself was destroyed. since the button that created the event is no more the event is ignored.

Comment: use javascript instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling events for dynamically generated .NET user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855215/handling-events-for-dynamically-generated-net-user-control)